# get selected razor radio button value in mvc on view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is my view page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestStarted","Student",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div style="margin-left: 30px;">
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <div>
                      @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model[i].TestID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model[i].QuestionId)
                    <span>@Model[i].QuestionName</span>
                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Options.Count(); j++)
                    {
                        <div>  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model[i].SelectedOption,Model[i].Options[j].OptionId, new {id="Radopt"})
                            <span>@Model[i].Options[j].OptionName</span>
                            @{
                                optionId = Model[i].Options[j].OptionId;   
                             }
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="pageCount" value="@ViewBag.ct" />
        <input type="button" value="End Test" />
    </div>
}

@{
       optionId = Model[i].Options[j].OptionId;   
 }
```

Now in this **optionid** i want **optionid** of only dat **option which is selected.**

but in this **option id i am getting last option id**.

can any one tell me how to get only **selected** **optionid**??

**my first loop is for question** and my **2nd loop is for option for particluar question**.

Comment: no body is der to help mee?????????????????????????????

Comment: show you post action how are you getting it?

Comment: i want this value on httpget not on post bcoz on post i am getting dat on post bt i want on httpget

Comment: i did'nt undertand what you want to acheieve?

Comment: i want selected option value on httpget method when i am clicking actionlink

Comment: you have get it via jquery if you want to but why not post form

Comment: bt i dnt want it on post.i have done paging means i am displaying 1 question per page and when user moves on second question then i want to preserve that value but problem is in my paging i have generated action link dynamically so

Comment: Put [HttpGet] on your actionlink to allow them to run on GET. Use FormMethod.Get instead of Post in code you have posted here.

Comment: If you want to store the selected radio button value then you will need to write a JS on checked event of radio button and store its value rather than what you have done right now i.e. **@{
                                optionId = Model[i].Options[j].OptionId;   
                             }**